# Change source IP of an incomming packet WIN7

Tags: nat, ip

I am receiving data through a specific TCP port and I would like to apply a rule on my Win7 Machine for my trafic (NAT??) :

Every Frame coming from A --> Change Source Address to B

&

Every Frame going to B --> Change Dest Address to A

Is there a way to make it work (through a software or with a native Win7 method) ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn't natively support NAT, however [Server 2008 does](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469812.aspx).

You could do this with a more advanced router/firewall, but not natively to Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to do PAT (kinda)  if you put a device between A and B you should be able to use PAT to mask/convert the specific port to that of the FW and vice versa.  You may be able to get this type of functionality out of a cheap managed soho firewall like a linksys.